# How to migrate data from one exasol version 5 to exasol version 6 without using files?

Tags: data-migration, exasolution

I wish to migrate data from exasol to exasol, but do not wish to use files as it would take a lot of time to move terabytes of data. I am totally new to exasol and have never worked on migration. Script is given on github (https://github.com/EXASOL/database-migration/blob/master/exasol_to_exasol.sql) but that is again using file import. Any lead would be appreciated!

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, we did this migration for ~80Tb compressed size (~400Tb raw size) database.

First of all, Exasol v6 works with data volumes created in v5 without any problems. There is no need to make this migration ASAP.

The simplest way is:

1. Upgrade to Exasol v6.
2. Create an archive volume, make full backup.
3. Create a data volume, restore backup.
4. Create new ExaSolution instance pointing to restored data volume.
5. If everything is ok, drop old Exasol instance and old data volume.

This is the fastest and easiest method, but you'll need a lot of disk space. It is a good idea to drop all indexes and truncate all staging tables to reduce size of backup.

Comment: Thanks for sharing it, but we do not want to do the full data migration with all schemas. Rather we want to be flexible with choosing the schemas that we wish to move.

Comment: @K_Learner, ok, in this case your only option is IMPORT FROM EXA. It is described in manual and moves data directly from one Exasol instance to another. It is also somewhat "parallel" and avoids creation of any files, but still much slower than restore from backup.

Comment: Yes, somewhat similar I have used..I also wanted to make sure that identity key is same across two versions. But the script is working for me now..thanks!